# Prevent hyphenation in \texttt words

Tags: symbols, hyphenation, typewriter

### Background

The text contains programming variable names such as `report_city` and `SUBREPORT_FILE`. All such variables are marked up with `\texttt`.

### Problem

Some variable names are hyphenated:

```
SUBREPORT_-
FILE
```

I would prefer that the variables are not subjected to hyphenation.

### Solution

A few ideas:

- Redefine `\texttt` to wrap an `\mbox{...}` command around the content. Best solution?
- Use `\uchyph0`. Did not work as expected.
- Define all the words using `\hyphenation{...}`. The command `\hyphenation{SUBREPORT\_FILE}` did not compile, and defining all the words would be a second last resort.
- Edit the entire document and put all variables inside `\mbox{...}` commands. I would consider this a last resort.

### Question

How would you prevent the texts from being hyphenated?

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you use `\verb|...|` or `\lstinline|...|` ?

Comment: @Herbert: There are hundreds, if not thousands of instances. I would prefer not to re-edit them all.

Comment: @Dave: ok, but it is only a search and replace which can be done in one run over all files with eg Perl

Comment: @Herbert: The document is being edited with LyX. As such, I would prefer keeping everything as `\texttt`, rather than adding more evil red text. But that is a possibility.

Comment: @Dave: did you load the package `hyphenat`? If yes then comment it out

Comment: What are you doing to let text mode underscores work fine? Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: @Seamus @Dave `texttt` is not the problem, please see my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\let\temptt\texttt
\renewcommand\texttt[1]{\mbox{\temptt{#1}}}
```

I have this break because latex doesn't like underscores in text mode, but I presume you have a way round this...

Comment: LyX automatically escapes the underscores (`\\_`). And thank you. This works flawlessly.

Comment: @Dave Aha! That's clever of LyX.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to put

```
\texttt{\hyphenchar\font=-1 }
```

early in your document. But I wonder why it is needed: When I try, the hyphenchar of the texttt font is already set to -1, as evidenced by running

```
\texttt{\showthe\hyphenchar\font}
```

But maybe you are using a different fixed-width font?

Comment: Thank you. LyX defines a "TypeWriter" font, which marks-up the text using `\texttt`'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem  is not the `texttt` as is evident from the short code below!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\printhyphens{\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox \setbox1\hbox{\strut}\vbox\bgroup
\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox \nobreak\hskip0pt\relax}\dimen0=\hsize
\hsize=0pt \hfuzz\maxdimen \def\par{\endgraf \hsize=\dimen0\getlastline
\egroup\endgraf}}\offinterlineskip\breakafterword}

\def\breakafterword{\catcode`\^^M\active\catcode`\ \active}
{\breakafterword\gdef^^M{\par}\global\let ^^M}

\def\getlastline{\setbox0\lastbox\ifvoid0\let\next\nomorelines
\else\unskip\unpenalty\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox0\strut\discretionary{}{}{}%
\unhbox1}\let\next\getlastline\fi\next}

\def\nomorelines{\unhbox1}
\begin{document}

\begingroup

\printhyphens
photograph photography photographer
photographical photographically
hypersupersuperdupercali%

\texttt{fragilisticexpihalidocious}

\texttt{photographer}
\end{document}
```

If we can see a minimal may be someone can find a solution!

Comment: The problem is breaking at underscores. Underscores cause an error on my system. So we need to know what @Dave Jarvis is doing with underscores to see the problem.

Comment: @Seamus it appears as the most likely cause for this.