# Comma-separated list

Tags: macros, lists

I would like to produce comma-separated lists, like "a, b, c, d" or "a, b, c, and d".

Requirements:

- In the Latex source code, each line of the source code should contain one list element, and as little additional markup as possible.
- It should be easy to re-order the entries by changing the order of source code lines.

For example, I could simply write the list elements like this:

```
a,
b,
c, and
d.
```

This would (almost) satisfy the first requirement, but it would fail on the second requirement. I would have to remember to fix the punctuation whenever I re-order the entries (or simply add a new entry). It sounds trivial, but it is surprisingly easy to forget to replace the full stop with a comma, and not that easy to spot the mistake. And I have a longish Latex document that mixes other content and such lists, so it would not be convenient to use an external script to generate the appropriate Latex code – I am really looking for something that is as easy as possible to maintain in the long term.

I do not really know what would be an appropriate interface; hence this can also be seen as an interface-design challenge. Perhaps something like this:

```
xxx\begin{commasep}[and]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
\end{commasep}yyy
```

would produce:

```
xxxa, b, c, and dyyy
```

(Note: no whitespace after "d", so that I can add appropriate punctuation right after the list.)

I wonder if, e.g., `paralist` can be tweaked to produce what I want?

Comment: I can't provide an answer, but if you think about tweaking `paralist`, have a look at the alpha version of `enumitem` 3.0 ([announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/9a439036423c2d29/)), which (finally) includes run-in lists.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks, that is great news indeed! I am using enumitem almost all the time, and I have tried to avoid the headache of mixing enumitem + paralist.

Comment: I could image something based on changing the catcode of the end-of-line character. This then doesn't work when the list is part of a macro argument. Would this be ok?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, it would be ok in my application.

Comment: Very pleased to see the Oxford comma in use: "a, b, c, and d".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here some macro which reads the lines as macro arguments.
It got inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10426/2975).
It would be possible to change the "interface" to LaTeX environments instead, but the TeX syntax (without `\begin` and `\end`) is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\commasep[2][, ]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\commasepsep{#1\space}%  store separator e.g. ','
   \def\commasependsep{#2\space}%  store last separator e.g. 'and'
   \@commasep
}
\newcommand*\@commasep[1][.]{%
   \def\commasepend{#1}%  store end marker e.g. '.'
   \@ifnextchar\endcommasep{}{%  check for empty list
     \catcode\endlinechar\active%  make end-of-line active
     \commasepfirstelement%  read first element
   }%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode\endlinechar\active%
% The `~` character represents the end-of-line character in the
% code below:
\lccode`\~=\endlinechar%
\lowercase{%
% Read first element
\gdef\commasepfirstelement#1~}{%
    #1%
    \@ifnextchar\endcommasep{%
      \commasepend% remove this if you don't want one with only one element
    }{%
      \commasepelement% no comma here!
    }%
}%
\lowercase{%
\endgroup%
% Read all other elements
\gdef\commasepelement#1~}{%
    \@ifnextchar\endcommasep{% Stop at `\endcommasep`
      \commasependsep#1\commasepend%
    }{%
      \commasepsep#1\commasepelement%
    }%
}%
\def\endcommasep{%
  \@gobble{endcommasep}% be unique (for `\@ifnextchar`) 
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Usage: \commasep[<separator>]{<last separator>}[<end marker>]
xxx\commasep[,]{and}[.]
a
b
c
d
\endcommasep yyy

xxx\commasep{and}
a
\endcommasep yyy

xxx\commasep{and}
\endcommasep yyy

xxx\commasep{or}
a
b
\endcommasep yyy

\end{document}
```

Please also note that there is a [`parselines`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parselines) package which might be used. However, it doesn't support handling the last entry different. Nevertheless, its code might be a good read for people interested in this kind of parsing.

Comment: Very nice.  Is there a reason for not adding the spaces in the definition of `\commasependsep`? That would make user input a lot more intuitive, rather than having to type `{ and }`. (And in fact, I would suggest an optional argument) `[,]` which would put in a comma before the 'and' if desired.  (It might also be useful to let the user specify the delimeter (',' or ';' for example) for the whole list too.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Good argument. I didn't added the spaces to allow for freedom to the user. He/she might want to use `{,}` instead of `{ and }` or use the funny American style `{, and }`. It's not a problem to add an optional argument, but this wasn't requested, so I didn't added it.

Comment: @Alan Munn: I added now optional arguments for the separator as well as the end marker: `\commasep[, ]{ and }[.]`. I kept the spaces as part of these arguments because of the above mentioned reason of flexibility.

Comment: @Martin While I see the need for flexibility, the extra spaces are very unintuitive as input. For example, would anyone want _no_ trailing space after the delimiter? (I'm making these comments because Jukka's question was also about what a good interface would be like; I'm not complaining about your solution!)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Ok, I added the spaces (`\space`) now, because it is simpler to remove them if they are not wanted than to add them if they are.

Comment: @Martin.  This no longer allows the Oxford comma (i.e., 'd, and e') since it puts a space before the and.  It also won't work for lists where you want the last element also to delimited by e.g. a ',' or ';'.  So perhaps the compromise is to force the user to add the preceding space in the final delimiter.  This would allow `{,}` or '{; and}` or `{ and}`.

Comment: @Alan: Ok, I removed the leading space before `and` again.

Answer (score 6):

Items are delimited by `,,`, and the list is ended with `..`. In fact, each `,,` should be followed by a space or the end of a line (without `%`). For very long lists (a few paragraphs?), this might get slow, since we grab the whole list as an argument at every step.

(Note that I "declare" each command with `\newcommand\command{}` to make sure they don't exist before I define them using `\def`.)

The whole construction relies on a generic macro to insert the desired separators between list elements, with some configuration possible. See e.g., `\commasepitem` below, which writes the list in an `itemize` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}    

\makeatletter
% #1 at the beginning
% #2 between each element
% #3 between the last two
% #4 after the last
% #5 is the first item
\newcommand*\commasep@generic{}
\def\commasep@generic#1#2#3#4 #5,, {#1#5\commasep@next{#2}{#3}{#4}}

\newcommand*\commasep@next{}
\def\commasep@next#1#2#3#4,, #5..{%
  % #1 is the list separator,
  % #2 is the last list separator,
  % #3 is the end text
  % #4 the item, 
  % #5 the rest.
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter a\detokenize{#5}a% test if #3 is empty.
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2#4#3}%
  {#1#4\commasep@next{#1}{#2}{#3}#5..}%
}%

\newcommand*\commasep[1]{\commasep@generic{}{, }{, #1 }{\ignorespaces}}
\newcommand*\commasepitem{%
  \commasep@generic{\begin{itemize}\item}{\item}{\item[(last)]}{\end{itemize}} }
\makeatother



\begin{document}

xx\commasep{and}
    a,,
    b,,
    c,,
    d,,
    ..
yyyy

xxx\commasepitem
    ``London bridge is falling down'' is much more frightening!,,
    c,,
    ``Mary had a little lamb, little lamb, little lamb'' is a nice
    little song that my mom used to sing,,
    d,,
    ..
yyyy

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With the help of [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) it is possible.

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{itemize*}[label={}, itemjoin={,}, itemjoin*={, and}]
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize*}
```

Output:

[image: outut]

Answer (score 1):

With a flexible interface for setting the separators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\commasep}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \jukka_commasep:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
  \ignorespaces
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\commasepsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jukka/commasep } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jukka_commasep:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jukka/commasep } { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jukka_commasep_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \str_if_eq_x:nnT { } { \seq_item:Nn \l__jukka_commasep_seq { -1 } }
   {
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__jukka_commasep_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  \seq_use:NVVV \l__jukka_commasep_seq
   \l__jukka_commasep_two_tl
   \l__jukka_commasep_more_tl
   \l__jukka_commasep_last_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { NVVV }

\keys_define:nn { jukka/commasep }
 {
  two  .tl_set:N = \l__jukka_commasep_two_tl,
  more .tl_set:N = \l__jukka_commasep_more_tl,
  last .tl_set:N = \l__jukka_commasep_last_tl,
  two  .initial:n = { ~and~ },
  more .initial:n = { ,~ },
  last .initial:n = { ,~and~ },
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
}yyy

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
 b \\
}yyy

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 d \\
}yyy

\commasepsetup{
  two=+,
  more=-,
  last=-,
}

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
}yyy

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
 b \\
}yyy

xxx\commasep{
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 d \\
}yyy

\end{document}
```

[image]