# Comma-separated list environment

Tags: macros, lists, environments, punctuation

This question is somewhat of a follow up to an answer to a previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11587/13522).

I would like to create a list environment (similar to itemize and enumerate) such that the output of the list environment is a comma-separated list.

For example, the following input:

```
\begin{commalist}
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
\end{commalist}
```

Should produce the following output:

```
Item A, Item B and Item C.
```

Additionally, it would be nice to be able to specify the use of a comma instead of the final and (so that the output is instead `Item A, Item B, Item C.`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{commalist}{description*}{4}
\setlist[commalist]{itemjoin={{,}},itemjoin*={{, and}},afterlabel=\unskip{{~}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{commalist}
    \item Item A
    \item Item B
    \item Item C
\end{commalist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there should be no comma before and, then delete it in the setting.

Comment: @Herbert. Wow, great! Thanks. Only problem I have is that the text from the list is spaced evenly along the row, whereas I want the whole text to be left-justified. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @JoshuaSpence: write the first entry as `\item[\kern-0.3em] Item A`. I suppose that there is no easy way to get rid of the space

Comment: @Herbert: that didn't work but \hfill does the job.

Comment: `\setlist[commalist]{before=\kern-0.3em, ...}` seems to work.

Comment: I find spacing is not good without also specifying `mode=unboxed`.  However in this case "`itemjoin*` is ignored".

Answer (score 7):

A solution with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ,xspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{commalist}[1][\space]{\spence_comma_list:V \BODY #1}
\seq_new:N \l_spence_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_comma_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_spence_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl % we have an empty element at the beginning
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_spence_items_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spence_comma_list:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Here is a comma list
\begin{commalist}
\item Item A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end{commalist}
and another
\begin{commalist}
\item Item A
\item Item B
\end{commalist}
and another
\begin{commalist}
\item Item A
\end{commalist}
which ends the game.
Another one to see that a period can follow
\begin{commalist}[.]
\item Item A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end{commalist}
\end{document}
```

A punctuation after the list should be specified beforehand as optional argument, because `\NewEnviron` works hard to gobble a space following `\end{commalist}`.

---

The code prior to the addition of `\seq_use:Nnnn` follows, just in order to appreciate the elegance of the new method. Thanks to Bruno for providing it.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{commalist}[1][\space]{\spence_comma_list:V \BODY#1}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_comma_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_spence_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl % we have an empty element at the beginning
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_spence_lastitem_tl
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_spence_items_seq
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_spence_lastitem_tl
   }
   {
    \spence_andify:
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_andify:
 {
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_spence_lastbutoneitem_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_spence_items_seq { ##1,~ }
  \tl_use:N \l_spence_lastbutoneitem_tl
  \c_space_token and ~ 
  \tl_use:N \l_spence_lastitem_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spence_comma_list:n { V }
\tl_new:N \l_spence_lastbutoneitem_tl
\tl_new:N \l_spence_lastitem_tl
\seq_new:N \l_spence_items_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: With the upcoming CTAN update (in July 2012), you'll be able to simplify this to `\seq_set_split:Nnn` and `\seq_use:Nnnn \l_spence_items_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Very nice and welcome addition!

Comment: And since `\seq_use:Nnnn` is expandable, coding it was a mess (no `\seq_pop_right:NN` available, for instance).

Answer (score 6):

The package `enumitem` may give a solution. Use `inline`-list. See section 4 in the manual, and especially the possibility to set up a list using `itemjoin` (see page 9).