# Using hfill to prevent expansion of text in table environment

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, inline

I am using inline lists (from the enumitem package) within a table (see [Comma-separated list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62613/comma-separated-list-environment)) Originally, I had an issue where the inline list would expand horizontally to the width of the table. I mostly fixed this using a `\hfill` after the inline list, but this doesn't seem to work for the last table row. Does anyone have any ideas how I could fix this?

[image]

Here is the relevant LaTeX code:

```
\newlist{commalist}{description*}{4}
\setlist[commalist]{itemjoin={{,}},itemjoin*={{ and}},afterlabel=\unskip{{~}}}`

\newenvironment{technicalSkills}%
{%
\def\lwidth{0.3\textwidth}%
\def\rwidth{0.64\textwidth}%
%
\newcommand\technicalSkillsItem[2]{%
\ifdef{\separator}{\separator}{}%
##1 & %
\begin{commalist}%
##2 %
\end{commalist}. \hfill %
\def\separator{\\[0.5em]}%
}%
%
\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}%
}
{\end{longtable}}


\section*{Technical Skills}
\begin{technicalSkills}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Programming Languages}
{\item C
\item C++
\item Java
\item Perl
\item Python}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Web-Based Development}
{\item PHP
\item JavaScript
\item CSS
\item HTML}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Document markup}
{\item \LaTeX}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Databases}
{\item Oracle
\item MySQL
\item postgreSQL}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Operating Systems}
{\item Microsoft Windows
\item Linux
\item Solaris}
%
\technicalSkillsItem{Tools}
{\item Git
\item Subversion
\item Eclipse IDE}
%
\end{technicalSkills}
```

Comment: Please, complete the code to a MWE.

Comment: Please always post complete documents that may be processed by latex. The fragment contains may undefined commands and undefined tablular L column, so it is virtually impossible for anyone to guess what it does or how to help make it do something different.

Comment: Just guessing, try a \\ before \end{technicalSkills}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `\phantom{}` after the end of the commalist (ie. `\end{commalist}. \phantom{}`). This seems to work best for me.

Comment: `\null` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `\par` before `\end{longtable}` in the definition of the `technicalSkills` environment.