# Comma-separated list environment and etoolbox

Tags: lists, expl3, etoolbox

I want to combine the automatic punctuation in comma separated list from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62620/22187) with the list processing from `etoolbox`.
However, I do not get any output.
What is going wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,environ,xspace,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{commalist}[1][\space]{\spence_comma_list:V \BODY #1}
\seq_new:N \l_spence_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_comma_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_spence_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl % we have an empty element at the beginning
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_spence_items_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spence_comma_list:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The new list works:
\begin{commalist}
 \item a
 \item b
 \item c
\end{commalist}

List processing from etoolbox works:
\forcsvlist{;}{a,b,c}

The combination does not work:
\begin{commalist}
\forcsvlist{\item}{a,b,c}
\end{commalist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Other than for academic interest, why would you even need the `commalist` environment, if you are providing input in the form of a comma separated list.  Would an answer that takes a comma separated list and turns it into `a, b and c` be equally acceptable?

Comment: I have a `bibtex` field containing a comma separated list. I am reading it using `\forcsvfield` from `biblatex` which is modeled after `\forcsvlist` from `etoolbox`. I want to include an `and` before the last item, but are also considering using a totally different separator, maybe a semicolon. If there is a better way to do it, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this syntax will support what the OP is trying to achieve, but the issue is, as is often the case, EXPANSION.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ,xspace,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{commalist}[1][\space]{\spence_comma_list:V \BODY #1}
\seq_new:N \l_spence_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_comma_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_spence_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_spence_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl % we have an empty element at the beginning
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_spence_items_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spence_comma_list:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\tmp{\begin{commalist}}
\edef\z{\forcsvlist{\noexpand\item}{a,b,c}}
\expandafter\tmp\z
\end{commalist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if one is not *forced* to use the `commalist` environment, other ways are easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\oxcomma[1]{%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\else
      \ifnum\listlen\mylist[]<3\else,\fi\ \fi
    \ifnum\zcnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax and \fi
    \z
  }
}
\newcommand\nooxcomma[1]{%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\else
      \ifnum\zcnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax\ and \else, \fi
    \fi
    \z
  }
}
\begin{document}
\noindent OPTION A:\\ % OXFORD COMMA
\oxcomma{A, B}\\
\oxcomma{A, B, C}

\medskip\noindent OPTION B:\\
\nooxcomma{A, B}\\
\nooxcomma{A, B, C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I did try expansion, but this was too involved for me. The solution using `commalist`  lost the ability to execute code directly before the begin of the item e.g. `\item\bf`. The Oxford comma solution fails for two entries, as there I would like to have no comma at all, only the `and`. I have to look into the `listofitems` package, I never used it before.

Comment: @JanHajer Please see my revision to fix your cited deficiency of the 2nd approach.

Comment: @JanHajer As to the `commalist` approach, you can either do it `\edef\z{\forcsvlist{\noexpand\item\noexpand\bfseries}{a,b,c}}` or else `\edef\z{\forcsvlist{\noexpand\item}{\noexpand\bfseries a,b,c}}`

Comment: By the way, @JanHajer, `listofitems` can provide powerful multi-level (nested) parsing.  Definitely check it out (https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using the `b` argument type of `\NewDocumentEnvironment` (thus not needing the `environ` package) and the `\unexpanded` primitive of e-TeX in order not to expand the contents too early (the harmless `a,b,c` in the example).

```
\documentclass{article}
% xspace not needed
% xparse not needed if the LaTeX kernel is from 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { commalist } { +b }
  { \spence_comma_list:n {#1} }
  { }

\seq_new:N \l__spence_items_seq

% From egreg: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62620/73317>
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spence_comma_list:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__spence_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
    % We have an empty element at the beginning:
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__spence_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__spence_items_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { , ~ and ~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The combination works:
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\noexpand\item \unexpanded{#1}}%
  \edef\zzz{%
    \endgroup
    \noexpand\begin{commalist}
    \docsvlist{a,b,c}%
  }\zzz
\end{commalist}.

\end{document}
```

[image]