# List delimited by commas (not lines)

Tags: lists, comma-separated-list

Note: [Delete an element from a comma delimited list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/comma-delimited-lists) is not a duplicate.

What I want to do is have a list environment of items, like itemize and enumerate, but I want the *output* to be delimited by commas instead of new lines.

Take this example from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures :

```
\begin{list_type}

  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc \ldots

\end{list_type}
```

I want the list type to output something that looks like this:

```
The first item, The second item, The third etc ...
```

With line breaks only when an item hits the right edge of the page. So if the right-hand margin were right after "third," we'd have,

```
The first item, The second item,
The third etc ...
```

instead of

```
The first item, The second item, The third
etc ...
```

Am I approaching this wrong in thinking that it should be a list structure? How can I do this with LaTeX?

Comment: This looks like something similar (minus the `and`): [Comma-separated list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11584)

Comment: Are your items fairly short in length? For example, what should happen to an item that spans more than one line? What about the layout around a page break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on Ulrike's code, here is how to box up the items so that they do not spread over a line break, as requested in the question:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newlength{\runindent}
\setlength{\runindent}{\parindent}
\newenvironment{runlist}
{\par\renewcommand\item{\ifvmode\hspace{\runindent}\else\unskip,\egroup\ \fi
\hbox\bgroup}\raggedright}
{\egroup\par}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Following line for demonstration purposes only
\setlength{\textwidth}{6cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

Some text for context to fill out space before the list and to show
the line lengths.
\begin{runlist}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc \ldots
\end{runlist}
Some text for context to fill out space after the list and to show
the line lengths.

\end{document}
```

The basic idea is to box up each item in an `\hbox`.  The `\hspace` command serves two purposes, firstly it forces latex in to horizontal mode, otherwise the first item will be treated as a box to be put on its own line, and secondly it gives you control over the initial indentation of the list via the new length `\runindent`.  (Note that you can't use `\parindent` directly, as this gets set to zero internally before arriving at this point.)  Finally the correct line breaking is achieved by setting the item boxes raggedright.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution can be something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newenvironment{runlist}
 {\par\renewcommand\item{\unskip\ifvmode\else, \fi}}
 {\par}


\begin{document}
some text
\begin{runlist}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc \ldots
\end{runlist}
some text
\end{document}
```

But the details can get tricky. E.g. if you want to suppress the comma in some cases you need an optional argument and so on.