# Generate comma separated list with some non-empty strings

Tags: macros, expansion, strings, xstring, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to generate a comma separated list that uses strings that may or may not be empty. For example `\mylist{\stringA,\stringB,\stringC}` would expand to `A, C` if `B` is empty or `B, C` if `A` is empty, etc.

In case it matters, the strings are generated with `xstring`, for example something like `\StrBetween[3,4]{\longstring}{text:}{,}[\stringC]` which may or may not be empty depending on whether the condition is met.

I'm pretty sure that I saw something similar somewhere, some time, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11584/9075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be done with pure expansion, but since you're using `xstring` it's not really necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{ m o }
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:No \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }
   }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   { \l_tmpa_clist }
   { \clist_set_eq:NN #2 \l_tmpa_clist }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\stringA{A}
\newcommand\stringB{}
\newcommand\stringC{C}

\begin{document}

\mylist{\stringA,\stringB,\stringC}

\mylist{\stringA,\stringB,\stringC}[\listA]

\show\listA


\end{document}
```

The `\show\listA` command produces

```
> \listA=macro:
->A,C.
```

Without an optional argument the result will be simply printed.

---

If you want to *print* the resulting list with a space following the comma, then a different approach is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{ m }
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_if_empty:oF { ##1 } { \seq_put_right:No \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\stringA{A}
\newcommand\stringB{}
\newcommand\stringC{C}

\begin{document}

\mylist{\stringA,\stringB,\stringC}


\end{document}
```

In case you want to avoid that `\newcommand{\stringB}{ }` prints a space, use `\tl_if_blank:oF` instead of `\tl_if_empty:oF`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me altering the code so as to not ignore white spaces in the list? I would like `A, C`.

Comment: @Jörg That's a different thing, then. So you want just to *print* the items?

Comment: Well, yes. Printing the items and the respective commas. Your solution is great - I like the `\show\listA`, but just with an extra whitespace between items.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\ifemptyarg#1{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58638/5764
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % H. Oberdiek
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
\providecommand{\listcomma}{}
\newcommand{\mylist}[2][,]{%
  \renewcommand{\listcomma}{\renewcommand{\listcomma}{#1}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to process each item
    \expandafter\ifemptyarg\expandafter{##1}
      {}% Do nothing
      {\unskip\listcomma{} \penalty0 ##1}% Print <,> <space> <item>
    }%
    \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
}
\begin{document}
\def\strA{strA}
\def\strB{strB}
\def\strC{}
\def\strD{strD}
\mylist{\strA,\strB,\strC,\strD}
\end{document}
```

The process above uses one of the options specified in [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764).