# How can I make a command that applies to a paragraph without curly braces?

Tags: macros, lists

I have to make an global change in many enumerate lists, so  in need define a command that I can apply without braces in a such way that only applies until the end of the paragraph (or line), for example

```
\item \changecolor  text text text text text text text text text text 
                     text text text text text text text text text.
 %defautl color
 othertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextot
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What is the change that you need to make?  Are you wanting to change enumerate, and then have it change back?  Could you post a minimal example that gives us a before and after (using braces if necessary so that we can see what you want to happen)?

Comment: Enumeration it's circumstantial. The command \changecolor applies to any paragraph
in a such way that when it realize that the paragraph end up, then, it stop (similar to  close the brace)

Comment: it's possible but fragile and can easily break other code in the document, is there any reason not to simply use `\item \textcolor{red}{text ...text}` ?

Comment: I need to apply this procedure to the exercise lists of an extended book. The natural solution would be to put curly braces at the beginning and end on hundreds of paragraphs. But that's what I want to avoid

Comment: But the solution you're looking for will still need you to put hundreds of `\changecolor`s at the beginning of paragraphs.  Is there some command or environment that is already present that you can simply modify?  The "right way to do it" would be to put some macro or environment around those exercises, even if it takes a few hours of work.  That would save you hours of headaches later, when a fragile command starts breaking other stuff.

Comment: Ok I found the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79002/define-a-command-to-affect-everything-until-the-end-of-the-paragraph?rq=1
Iit woks perfectly for my purposes. Thanks for your comments

Comment: teepeemm I only have to make replace \item by \item \changecolor because paragarphs alreade have a "blank line" to separate them

Answer (score 1):

```
\def\changecolor{\begingroup\def\par{\endgroup\par}\color{red}}
```