# Hide or show complete rows of longtabu or longtable LaTeX table

Tags: longtable, tabu, longtabu

I would like to toggle on/off complete rows of a longtabu or longtable
table.  The following post:

[hide/show complete row of tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419220)

provides elegant working solutions (which I presume are roughly identical) for a tabular environment table.

Unfortunately, when used with a longtabu or longtable table or,
indeed, even just the tabu table environment, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Paragraph ended before \rowswitch was complete.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.208   \end{longtabu}

--- HELP ---
A blank line occurred in a command argument that shouldn't contain
one. You probably forgot the right brace at the end of an argument.
```

My table is very long, so I would seem to need to use either the
longtabu or longtable environments.

I'm using the memoir class, but I seem to get the same error with the
article class.

The following is a MWE (using the Carlisle solution) that does not work in just the above way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,10pt,oneside,english]{memoir}
% memoir set margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}      % left-right
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}      % upper-lower
\checkandfixthelayout 

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%  toggle switches to hide/unhide rows of table:
%  \def\rowswitch#1\\{#1\\} %On = Unhide
\def\rowswitch#1\\{} %Off = Hide

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to\textwidth{
| X[2,l]
| X[2,l]
| X[15,l]
| X[15,l]
| X[2,l]
| }
\hline \hline
\textbf{Ref} & 
\textbf{Ref} & 
\textbf{Summary} &
\textbf{Summary} &
\textbf{Ref}
\\ \hline \hline \hline \hline
&
&
\blindtext
&  
&
\\ \hline
\rowswitch       
&       
Hidden row
&
Hidden row
 \blindtext
 &
 Hidden row
 &
 \\ \hline
 &
 & 
 \blindtext
 &
 &
 \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

For longtable, one can substitute:

```
\begin{longtable}{
| p{1cm}
| p{1cm}
| p{10cm}
| p{10cm}
| p{1cm}
| }
```

and

```
\end{longtable}
```

to get the same error.

Comment: remove all the blank lines (or define `\rowswitch` by `\long\def`)

Comment: Thanks David, `\long\def\rowswitch#1\\{}` etc works much better and remains very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all the blank lines (or define `\rowswitch` by `\long\def` or `\newcommand` rather than `\def`).

Removing the blank lines is perhaps the best solution as blank lines should never be used just for "pretty printing" the source layout in TeX, they are an instruction and reported as `\par` by TeX's file reading code. A paragraph break is not expected here (which is why the error is raised).

However even if you do remove the blank lines you should still make the command `\long` so that you can skip over paragraphs in `p` columns.

Comment: Thanks again, particularly for the explanation.  I guess it highlights the way in which LaTeX doesn't quite provide the form - content separation that one might expect.  The table is about 40 pages long so I suspect there are going to be blank lines. I hope to learn a bit more about how these macros work when I get some time.