# \multicolumn in newenvironment/NewEnviron

Tags: environments, multicolumn

I would like to include a multicolumn-row in a tabular environment if `\lehrertrue`. Otherwise nothing should happen. I tried `newcommand`, `newenvironment` and `NewEnviron` and always end up with a "misplaced `\omit`". Apparently I am unable to convince `\multicolumn` that it is starting a new row.
My last try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[cp437de]{inputenc}
\newif\iflehrer
\lehrertrue
\NewEnviron{lehrer}{\iflehrer{\multicolumn{5}{l}{\parbox{17cm}{\BODY}}}{{}}/fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlccl}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\begin{lehrer}
just a test\\
\end{lehrer}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Any helpful suggestions please?

P.S. I was unable to include something like "misplaced `\omit`" tag.

P.P.S. So far I have also been unable to find out whether `nicematrix` could solve the problem. "! LaTeX Error: Command `\iint` already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: An environment adds `\begingroup` and this stops the lookup for `\omit`, so `\multicolumn` appears when the table cell has already started.

Comment: Could the answers to these questions be helpful? [Conditionally coloring table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell) and [Cell content added conditionally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455895/tabular-with-conditional-rows-based-on-content).

Comment: Concerning `nicematrix`, your remark is rather strange because `\nicematrix` does not define any  command `\iint`...

Comment: I think this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419225/101651 could help you