# \newcommand for \ifdefined

Tags: ifthenelse

Is there a possibility to design a \newcommand for the if-structure?

I want to shorten the

`\ifdefined\todo text \fi`

into something where I simply need to write
`\todo text`

without the \fi.

Comment: you need something to end the text the normal document form would not use ifdefined but simply `\todo{text}` which you can define with newcomnand

Comment: `\newcommand\todo[1]{#1}` then `\todo{foo}`. And if you don't want text to appear in later versions you could use `\newcommand\todo[1]{}` instead.

Comment: Welcome! Have you checked the [comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) or [todo](https://ctan.org/pkg/todo?lang=en) packages?

Comment: How's TeX supposed to know where the text you want to feed `\todo` with will end?

Comment: See also [macros - \def taking rest of the line as argument - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10426/def-taking-rest-of-the-line-as-argument) but depends on what you need...