# Define custom command which captures whole paragraph

Tags: environments, exam, renewcommand

I am using the [exam document class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam). It has commands like `\question` which operate inside the environment `questions`. Within the document, you can write things like

```
\begin{questions}
\question Here is the text of the question.
\end{questions}
```

I have defined a custom `\mquestion` command within this for mathematics exams that adds a few additional features like auto-scaling space for the answer and prints the number of marks in the format I want:

```
\newcommand{\mquestion}[2]{\question[#1] #2
\begin{solution}[\stretch{#1}]
\end{solution}
    
\hfill \fillin
    
\droppoints
}
```

I use it by typing things like `\mquestion{3}{Text of the question.}`.

Is there a way I can define a custom command that works like the original `\question` command and does not require the question text to be in braces?

Putting it in general terms, I want to be able to define a command like

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{A#1B}
\test abc
```

which produces the output AabcB instead of AaB bc. The default behaviour seems to be that if braces are omitted the command only "captures" one character. I want it to capture all the way to the end of the paragraph. I notice that `\item` within the `\itemize` environment works this way, so perhaps this is something to do with environments.

Comment: Related question [macros - \def taking rest of the line as argument - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10426/def-taking-rest-of-the-line-as-argument)

Comment: note `\question` is like `\item` so not like the command you ask for, it never processes the text, just sets the heading and setsup the layout